# How to iterate through all characters in string then check if any characters contain lowercase, uppercase, digits, and punctuation and return True

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a string contains any characters that are lowercase, uppercase, a digit, or punctuation and if any are then return True, but whenever i run it the code only checks the first character. Am i iterating incorrectly?

I've tried to create conditionals that check if a character is lowercase, uppercase, a digit, or punctuation, and if it is then return true. else return false.

this is what i have at the moment:

```
def check_characters(password, characters):
    '''Put your docstring here'''
    for i in password:
        if i.islower():
            return True
        if i.isupper():
            return True
        if i.isdigit():
            return True
        if i.punctuation():
            return True
        else:
            return False



def main():

    password = "n11+"
    print(check_characters(password, ascii_lowercase))
    print(check_characters(password, ascii_uppercase))
    print(check_characters(password, digits))
    print(check_characters(password, punctuation))
```

I expect it return True for the lowercase if the character contains a lowercase, and the same for the other call to functions, but the actual output is all True when it should only be true for the lowercase, digit, and punctuation

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to return `True` only if *all* characters in your string are alphanumeric or punctuation, or if at least one of them is? Your question seems to suggest the latter, but the former would be more suitable for this context.

Comment: Get rid of the `else`, and move the `return False` to *after* the `for` loop.  The way it is now, you are always returning something after looking at the first character, no matter what.

Comment: Ah sorry, I would like it to return True if at least one of the characters is alphanumeric or punctuation.

Comment: @csstudent See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning after the first iteration; plus, you aren't using your `characters` argument.

You only want to return true if you encounter a character in `characters`. If you don't encounter any such characters, return false:

```
from string import *

def check_characters(password, characters):
    # convert to set for better performance
    characters = set(characters)
    for i in password:
        if i in characters:
            return True
    return False


def main():
    password = "n11+"
    print(check_characters(password, ascii_lowercase))
    print(check_characters(password, ascii_uppercase))
    print(check_characters(password, digits))
    print(check_characters(password, punctuation))
```

You can simplify this with the `any` function:

```
def check_characters(password, characters):
    # convert to set for better performance
    characters = set(characters)
    return any(i in characters for i in password)
```

Anyway, in both cases, running `main` will output:

```
True
False
True
True
```

Comment: ahh thank you! I didn't realize making characters into a set would make it easier, also didn't know the else was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem here is that you `return` after checking the first character. To do what you want, you should `return True` *only if* any of the conditions are fulfilled.

If none are, then you should go to the next character, and *only when you have gone through all the characters, but none fulfil those conditions*, should you `return`:

```
from string import punctuation

def check_characters(password):
    '''Put your docstring here'''
    for i in password:
        if any((i.isalpha(), i.isdigit(), i in punctuation)):
            return True
    return False
```

(I typed this before the edit to the question, so I'll just leave it here for completeness)

That, at least, is what your question says. However, given the context (you seem to be checking the validity of a password), I think that what you want is really to assert that *all* the characters in the string satisfy the given constraints. If so, then you would need to invert the conditions:

```
def check_characters(password):
    '''Put your docstring here'''
    for i in password:
        if not all((i.isalpha(), i.isdigit(), i in punctuation)):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: okay i think i understand the issue. Thank you for your input, especially given my bad explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
import string
def check_characters(password, characters):
    '''Put your docstring here'''
    for i in password:
        if i.islower():
            return True
        if i.isupper():
            return True
        if i.isdigit():
            return True
        if i in string.punctuation:
            return True
```

You have to use this because you did an `else`, and `return` only outputs once, so if you didn't have that, it won't return and keep running.